# Referencing a previous instance of a class in current instance in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python and very much appreciate any help I can get!

I have created a class and I am hoping to combine two lists from a previous instance of the class with the same lists in the current instance of the class.

This is my current code:

```
def merge(self, another_flu_tweets):
    self.another_flu_tweets = another_flu_tweets
    import self.another_flu_tweets 
    self.tweets = self.tweets + self.another_flu_tweets.tweets 
    self.labels = self.labels + self.another_flu_tweets.labels
```

The error says no Module self.another_flu_tweets and occurs at the import line.

I have ran a code to create an instance of the class and then input the name of that instance as the argument for the merge method.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I can reference a previous instance of a class in the current instance of a class? Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Currently using:

```
another_flu_tweets = flu_tweets()
current_flu_tweets = flu_tweets()
```

and then I ran

```
current_flu_tweets.merge('another_flu_tweets')
```

Comment: `import` is used to import objects from python packages (i.e. different files). What do you mean under "previous instance of a class"? Could you please provide more source code to show your logic?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve with this `import self.another_flu_tweets ` line. `import` is for gaining access to code in one module from another. What exactly do you mean "a previous instance?" Do you still have a reference to that instance? Is it `another_flu_tweets`? If so, `self.tweets = self.tweets + another_flu_tweets.tweets` should work. That's what objects are for.

Comment: Sorry I am still trying to get the terminology down. Basically I have created a class, that contains a list of tweets and a list of labels and I want to concatenate that with a list of tweets and labels from a current instance of a class I am working on.

Comment: Can you show us how you ran your code?

Comment: Sorry I am still trying to get the terminology down. I have class flu_tweets
 Then there is code that makes a list of tweets and a list of labels
    def merge(self, another_flu_tweets): (With code from above)
To test: another_flu_tweets = flu_tweets() current_flu_tweets = flu_tweets() and then I ran current_flu_tweets.merge('another_flu_tweets') To try and import the list I needed. I was hoping to be able to concatenate the lists of tweets and labels from the two instances of the class.

Comment: @Emily You may add the code to your question. In any case pass the name of the instance without the quotations: `current_flu_tweets.merge(another_flu_tweets) `. Using the quotes makes it a string which will complicate your code.

Comment: @Emily I went ahead and added your code for you, but in the future, please add any clarifications to the question directly, not as a comment. Also, Moses Koledoye has your answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!! Removing the quotes fixed everything!!!!!!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name of the instance without the quotations, as using quotations makes it a string which will complicate your code:

```
current_flu_tweets.merge(another_flu_tweets)
```

Once you've passed the name of the other instance to a method in your current class, you'll simply do:

```
def merge(self, another_flu_tweets):
    self.tweets = self.tweets + another_flu_tweets.tweets 
    # or self.tweets += another_flu_tweets.tweets
    self.labels = self.labels + another_flu_tweets.labels
```

[`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) statements are used for *imports*; not sure of what you were expecting that to do.

The `self` reference on the other hand is a name (conventionally used) to refer to the current *instance* of the class within a *method*. So you would not need to set up an instance attribute that references the other instance i.e. `self.another_flu_tweets` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you! This was actually what I tried first but I get an error saying, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tweets'" Do you know how I can avoid this error?

Comment: You're passing the name as a string. Remove the quotations `''`